# Testing subdomains in capybara/rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm currently almost at the end of a long journey into rails testing, but I'm banging my head on how to get request specs working with subdomains.

In development, I'm using pow with urls such as: `http://teddanson.myapp.dev/account` which is all fine and dandy.

In testing, I let capybara do it's thing which returns localhost `http://127.0.0.1:50568/account` which obviously doesn't play nice with the whole subdomain thing. It works fine for the public part of the app that doesn't require subdomains, but how to access a given user's subdomain account is beyond me.

The relevant routes are accessed via these methods:

```
class Public
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.blank? || request.subdomain == 'www'
  end
end

class Accounts
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www'
  end
end
```

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills, so if anyone has any advice or suggestions to help me out that'd be very, very awesome. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xip.io to test subdomains in Capybara/RSpec, as described here: https://web.archive.org/web/20171222062651/http://chrisaitchison.com/2013/03/17/testing-subdomains-in-rails/

Comment: Detailed and elegant solution using 37signals xip.io.  Thank you! @cmaitchison

Comment: In the original article author uses xip.io. But that means that such tests need internet connection and without it they will fall! And also that should slow down the test suit because on each test with subdomain it will go firstly to the site.

Comment: The link mentioned in the answer is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot use subdomain in capybara's test but I have a workaround for this problem.
I have helper class for resolving a subdomain from the request, see:

```
class SubdomainResolver
  class << self
    # Returns the current subdomain
    def current_subdomain_from(request)
      if Rails.env.test? and request.params[:_subdomain].present?
        request.params[:_subdomain]
      else
        request.subdomain
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As you see, when the app is running in `test` mode and a special `_subdomain` request param is set the subdomain is taken from the request param called `_subdomain` otherwise `request.subdomain` (normal subdomain) is used.

To make this workaround work you have to also override url builders, in `app/helpers` create the following module:

```
module UrlHelper
  def url_for(options = nil)
    if cannot_use_subdomain?
      if options.kind_of?(Hash) && options.has_key?(:subdomain)
        options[:_subdomain] = options[:subdomain]
      end
    end

    super(options)
  end

  # Simple workaround for integration tests.
  # On test environment (host: 127.0.0.1) store current subdomain in the request param :_subdomain.
  def default_url_options(options = {})
    if cannot_use_subdomain?
      { _subdomain: current_subdomain }
    else
      {}
    end
  end

  private

  # Returns true when subdomains cannot be used.
  # For example when the application is running in selenium/webkit test mode.
  def cannot_use_subdomain?
    (Rails.env.test? or Rails.env.development?) and request.host ==  '127.0.0.1'
  end
end
```

`SubdomainResolver.current_subdomain_from` can be also used as constraint in `config/routes.rb`

I hope it will help you.